# Update Azure Pipeline Task Completion Status via REST API

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

Below is my YAML release pipeline code:

```
- stage: Stage1
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    displayName: Test
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: Delay@1
      displayName: I am waiting for you..
      inputs:
        delayForMinutes: 300
      TimeOutInMinutes: 299
```

I have included a Delay task set to wait for 5 hours and fail if its status isn't updated through our tooling.

I need to use Azure DevOps REST APIs to update the status of the above Delay task (to completed or passed) when the pipeline runs, ensuring it succeeds before reaching a timeout of 299 minutes.

So, How can I make the above task as completed/succeeded ?

Comment: Hi @owesom, have you checked my answer below? If you want a REST API to update the state of one task, you can submit a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestio). Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a REST API can update the state of a task. For YAML pipeline, you can only update the state of one **build** using REST API [Builds - Update Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update-build?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

[image]